# Programmatically open new browser tab with Silverlight and set content

Tags: javascript, silverlight

Was wondering if there is any way in Silverlight to open a new browser tab and set its content. In short, my app receives files (binary data) and needed to have the user's browser presenting them.

My app downloads contents (images/pdfs/whatever) from repositories from the cloud and stores them as binary data in a local cache; then after that I need a way to display those now local contents to the end user in a new tab. The "new tab" requirement is due to silverlight not supporting rendering of many file types such as .gif, .pdf and others - things that browsers handle easily, either natively or with widely used plugins. So my current WTF-y solution uses System.Windows.Browser and consists in the following:

```
        // Get document and body
        var doc = HtmlPage.Document;
        var body = doc.Body;

        // Create a <form> element and add it to the body
        var newForm = doc.CreateElement("form");
        newForm.SetAttribute("action", "www.example.com/contentpresenter.php");
        newForm.SetAttribute("enctype", "multipart/form-data");
        newForm.SetAttribute("method", "POST");
        newForm.SetAttribute("target", "_blank");
        body.AppendChild(newForm);


        var inp = doc.CreateElement("input");
        inp.SetAttribute("type", "text");
        inp.SetAttribute("name", "mcontent");
        inp.SetAttribute("value", Tools.ToBase64( content.Content as Stream ));
        newForm.AppendChild(inp);

        var inpt = doc.CreateElement("input");
        inpt.SetAttribute("type", "text");
        inpt.SetAttribute("name", "tcontent");
        inpt.SetAttribute("value", content.ContentType);
        newForm.AppendChild(inpt);

        // Send away!
        newForm.Invoke("submit");
```

In short, it creates a javascript script that posts the content to a remote PHP script which in turn does nothing more than decoding and presenting the content, which will open in a new tab. Yes, I'm fully aware of how idiotic it sounds - but does the trick and works as intended.

As far as I know, creating a new HtmlWindow and building up/altering its contents is not an option due to security constraints. An obvious option is having Silverlight produce javascript which would in turn create a new tab that loads the provided content, but javascript is not too big in handling binary or base64 data - at least not cross-browser seamlessly - and the whole thing seems stupid anyways.

Is there a solution to achieve this solely through Silverlight, or at least with a minimum amount of javascript involved? Alternatively, is there any javascript library you would recommend to handle base64 data?

Best regards!

Comment: Hi, were you able to find a solution? I am running against the exact same issue and there is no clear answer

Comment: Nope. Still using the idiotic solution described above.

Answer (score 0):

I recomend you to find Telerik's silverlight components sources and use RadHtmlPlaceholder (slightly buggy).
+ You can enable trusted application to run inside the browser for SL 5 and use WebBrowser control (best quality) but for windows only.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'd rather not use external components - and certainly not Telerik's in particular. Unfortunately usage of  WebBrowser is also not an option since cross-OS compatibility is also a requirement. Nevertheless, I appreciate you taking the time to make those suggestions.